# Webview broadcast intent scheme and broadcast receiver feedback message Android/iOS

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

Hi I need help with a scenario, my web url https://myweburl.com/intent when rendered in a mobile browser like chrome shows a link with an intent scheme e.g. upi://a=b&c=d&etc=etc,
one the user clicks this link Andriod show list of applications that understands this intent scheme. User selects one of those apps and continues his journey on the selected app. All these are working fine.

I want to know in the webpage js if user did redirect to any app from the list or did he select cancel. Or if possible get the name of the app that user selected from the list

[image]

How can Broadcast Intent (specifically webview or a browser) get meta information from andriod.

Comment: Hi, so, do you need to handle the name of the application that the user selected?

Comment: I need some identifier to identify the app that user selected, some before-hook that collects the name of the app that user selected to go further.

Comment: Try this https://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2021/05/07/detecting-which-app-was-used-to-share-your-apps-content/